# Virtualbox and Ruby on Rails application : How to access to the application's files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtualbox

New to webdevelopment and virtualization I just installed the Ruby On Rails Turnkey appliance on my computer using Virtualbox.

The installation was easy but there is one thing the newbie I am do not understand.

Via Vista's Explorer I just can't find the files of the 2 ROR applications I created with the Web Shell.

I know I created one new hard drive when installing the ROR appliance. I was just wondering whether I can access to these files via Vista's Explorer (if it is possible)
(I know I can do it via the Web Shell).

Does the .vdi file (the file containing the ROR appliance hard drive) act like a black box ? I just can't see there how many files are in this .vdi file.

Additional info :
OS : Vista

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: You can share folders between your VB and your OS. Also this question more fit [superuser](superuser.com)

Comment: thanks fl00r. I can't install the guest additions >> can't use the shared folders feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails appliance (and any TurnkeyLinux appliance) isn't going to share files by default.  The easiest way for you to get in will be to use an SSH/SFTP client to access the folders on the system.

**SSH/SFTP connection**

For my Turnkey boxes I use [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org) to connect as `root@10.0.2.15:22`.  Note that the actual IP address will change but you should see it on the blue splash screen after your Turnkey guest VM has booted.

**Port Forwarding - last resort**

If for some reason you can't access the IP address listed on that screen then you can set up [port forwarding](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) in the Virtualbox settings under **Devices > Network Adapters > Port Forwarding**.  In that case you'll forward host port 2222 to guest port 22.  Once that's done retry a FileZilla connection to `root@localhost:22`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much. Your answer helped me solve the problem (I didn't even have to forward the port). My first steps in Filezilla ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an another solution (no Turnkey, just Ubuntu in VirtualBox, but who prevent you from installing additional software?), **Samba server** on virtual machine. On windows I mount samba share as network drive, so I can access it like local files.